# Network configuration with limited hardware

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have cable internet and I have two PC. One of them has wireless and ethernet, the other pc has ethernet only. Also, I have a dsl modem that has wireless builtin (some common speedstream model).

My goal is to connect all of them so that both have internet access.

As I understand, I have two options: connect speedstream to the cable and then connect other PC's to speedstream; OR, connect pc with wireless to the cable and then connect the other pc that has ethernet only using ethernet+wireless through speestream.

First one seems to be easy, but it doesn't seem to work. What about the other choice? Is it possible to do it?

Comment: So do you have two ISPs? You mention *"cable internet"* but don't mention any cable modem.  You mention a *"dsl modem"* but don't mention any DSL service. If the *"speedstream"* is really a *"dsl modem"*, then you cannot use it for a *"cable internet"* service.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. I have cable service and cable modem obviously. I don't have dsl service, but I have my own dsl modem that happen to have wireless built-in and I want to reuse the wireless part of it to connect one more PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of possible options.

- Connect your router through ethernet to either of your PCs, share the connection and connect your two PCs through ethernet (requires 2xRJ45 cables):

```
            +------+     +----+     +----+
INTERNET----|router|-----| PC |-----| PC |
            +------+     +----+     +----+
                             shared connection
```

- Connect your router through ethernet to the PC without wireless capability (here `PC1`), and connect the other PC over WiFi:

```
            +------+     +---+
INTERNET----|router|-----|PC1|
            +------+     +---+
                |                  +---+
                +---(·)    (·)-----|PC2|
                       Wifi        +---+
```

- Get internet by WiFi on the PC that can (`PC2`), share the connection and connect your 2 PCs through ethernet:

```
            +------+
INTERNET----|router|
            +------+              
                |                  +---+     +---+
                +---(·)    (·)-----|PC2|-----|PC1|
                       Wifi        +---+     +---+
                                      shared connection
```

I'd strongly recommend to go with solution 2, as it allows both PCs to have internet even if the PC with the shared connection is off, and you don't have to bother setting up a shared connection.

Comment: Very good answer. The problem is that I'm not sure if I have the router. The speedstream has 4 ethernet ports, but it doesn't have the regular WAN port that routers have. So, when i plug in ethernet from cable modem to the wireless ap, it will be assigned an IP etc from provider. I have no clue how I can configure everything else so that they know that they should connect through that cable connection. If it was regular wireless ap, then it would be 5 minut thing: plug cable ethernet to router's WAN port and all other devices to other ethernet ports or wireless.

Comment: I used simple routers at home, but I'm not very good in terminology in case if something that I say sounds strange ;)

Comment: and the device that I have is SpeedStream 6520

Comment: Have you just tried to connect your ISP cable to an ethernet port on the router, a pc to another ethernet port, and tried to access the internet? on this [image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SpeedStream_6520_Derri%C3%A8re.JPG), the yellow label says LAN/WAN.

Comment: That "LAN/WAN" port should work, provided that you enable it for WAN use through the "Gateway LAN/WAN Port" web-based configuration page.  That is an unusual feature for an ADSL modem/router.  BTW the "best" configuration would be to use individual wired Ethernet connections from each PC to the router, which is not shown.

Comment: thanks everybody, I figured it after after trial and error. Ethernet from cable modem to WAN port on the dsl router. Some wait time with cable modem so that it gives it IP and then it all started to work.